# large deviation problem with rate function

Tags: probability, large-deviation-theory

Let X1, X2, . . . be i.i.d. random variables such that 
$P(X_1 = -1) = 2/3$ and $P(X_1 = 2) =1/3$

and for each integer $n \geq 1$ put $S_n := X_1 +X_2 +\cdots+X_n$. For a sufficiently large $n$,
which of the following events is more likely
$\{S_n \geq n/2\}$ or $\{S_n \leq -n/2\}$?

My Attempt: Use large deviation and see that the probability for the first event is $e^{-nI(n/2)}$ and the probability for the second is $1-e^{-nI(-n/2)}$. I know that both decrease to 0 but with different rates. But how do I tell which one decreases faster?

Answer (score 0):

We compute the log moment generating function $\Lambda$ of $X_1$,
$$\Lambda(\lambda) = \log \mathbb{E}\Big[e^{\lambda X_1}\Big] = \log\Big(\frac{1}{3}e^{2\lambda} + \frac{2}{3} e^{-\lambda}\Big)$$
[The Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)) tells us that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}\Big(S_n \geq n/2\Big) = -I(1/2)$$
and 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log\mathbb{P}\Big(S_n \leq -n/2\Big) = -I(-1/2),$$
where $I$ is called the rate function and is defined as (when $-1 < x < 2$)
\begin{align*}
I(x) &= \sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} \big( \lambda x - \Lambda(\lambda)\big)\\ &= \frac{1}{3} \bigg(\log\Big(\frac{(x-2)^2 (1 + x)}{4} \Big) + 
     x\log\Big(\frac{2 (1 + x) }{2-x}\Big)\bigg). 
\end{align*}
Numerically $I(1/2) = 0.059$ and $I(-1/2) = 0.07$, this tells you the probability of $\{S_n \geq n/2\}$ is bigger than that of $\{S_n \leq -n/2\}$ when $n$ is sufficiently large.